# Checking device volume level in Flutter for iOS and Android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an application built with Dart/Flutter that has user interaction that depends on the device's volume being on/turned up. I'm not seeing any obvious tutorials or packages available to determine this. How would I best go about approaching this? Am I overlooking a package or solution?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the current packages support Android only.

https://pub.dev/packages/volume - Android only ([example](https://here4you.tistory.com/245))

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_volume/ - iOS and Android ([example](https://www.yuque.com/befovy/share/flutter_volume#GHEEm))

```
import 'package:flutter_volume/flutter_volume.dart';

// Return relative volume as double between 0.0 and 1.0
await FlutterVolume.volume;
```